# need help in predicate logic

Tags: logic

How would you get from $\neg(\forall x)(Ax \to Bx)$ to $(\exists x)(Ax \land \neg Bx)$ with the rules of replacement & change of quantifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&\lnot \forall x ~(Ax \Rightarrow Bx) \\\iff &\lnot \forall x ~(\lnot Ax \lor Bx) \\\iff &~~~\exists x ~\lnot (\lnot Ax \lor Bx) \\\iff&~~~\exists x ~(Ax \land \lnot Bx)\end{align}$$